# MIcrochip PIC30 compiler under Linux

Tags: microchip

I'm trying to find a version of the Microchip PIC30 v1.24 compiler that will run in Linux. I understand that this compiler version is only available for Windows. What would be my best option without going to the newer XC compilers which do work on Linux ?

Comment: You could try installing the Windows one in Linux using Wine. I did this with an older version of MPLAB and the C compiler and it worked fine. http://www.winehq.org/

Comment: The tag `compiler` should be applied to questions concerning the programming of compilers or for questions about the detailed inner workings of compilers. Don't use `compiler` for questions about options and settings for a particular compiler, use the name of the compiler you are interested in instead.

Answer (score 0):

C30 compilers didn't have a Linux installer; this compiler was only compatible to Windows platform.

The best options would be:

1. Migrate to XC16 compiler which can be installed on Linux / Mac / Windows platforms
2. Move your PIC30 v1.24 based PIC24 design to a supported Windows platform (Windows xp)

**If none of these are possible, and you want to reinvent the wheel, rebuild a compiler using the PI24 source code available on "microchip.com/archives"**

(Note: Building a compiler from source code may not be as straightforward as one might expect it to be and would need prior experience in scripting and rebuilding toolchains)